# facebook App permission duration time

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm using a facebook app on two fan page. This app requires permissions to publish on the timeline and access to the data of the users. I used this app about 3 months ago on an old fan page. Now I want to use it in the new fan page. When an user who used this app 3 months ago tries to use the app, it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Oh..hehe...sorry about that!

Comment: You're talking about a page tab application correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a page tab app! :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses an access_token to authenticate a user and allow certain permissions, but this token does expire after some time. It simply doesn't last for 3 months.

Depending on how you implemented your application, you'll want to simply check for the permissions before you execute an action that requires permissions. Query this endpoint to see what permissions your user has granted you:

```
/me/permissions
```

The response can be quite extensive :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "basic_info": 1, 
      "read_stream": 1, 
      "manage_friendlists": 1, 
      "read_mailbox": 1,  
      "publish_stream": 1, // <--- I think this is the one you're looking for
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

If you find that the user doesn't have the required permissions then prompt them with the same thing you would to a brand new user - a login process. The actual login popup will be skipped (because the user has already installed the application) and they will only be presented with a request for permissions that they have not granted.